# How do I pass this initial state value using redux in my component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, react-router-v4, multer

I am using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to handle image uploads to my Next.js app. And I'm using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) for state management...

That being said, I created a property in my store called `userAvatar` for an eventual avatar for my profile page.

I noticed despite using `mapStateToProps`, `userAvatar` is not showing amongst the props of the `Profile` component and thus resulting in the image not persisting.

**NO** `userAvatar` prop!
[image]

Here is my profile component:

```
import { Button, Card, Feed, Icon, Image, Segment, Grid, Divider, Container, Header } from 'semantic-ui-react'

import MyHeader from '../Header/Header.jsx'
import ImageUploader from '../ImageUploader/ImageUploader.jsx';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { modalStateOn, modalStateOff } from '../../store/reducers/ui/index'
import { loadAvatar } from '../../store/reducers/users/index'


const ProfilePage = ({ history, isMobileFromSSR, userAvatar,...props }) => {

  function handleImageUpload() {
   setProfileImage(true);
  }

 return (
  <>
 {console.log("userAvatar ", userAvatar)}
 {console.log('Profile Page!! ', props)}
     <Grid container columns={1} relaxed stackable>
      <Grid.Column>
        <MyHeader as='h2' content='Foo' textAlign='left' />
      </Grid.Column>
    </Grid>

    <Grid container columns={2} divided relaxed stackable>
      <Grid.Column>
        <Segment>
         <Card fluid>
          <Image src='static/profile-avatars/charly_desktop.jpg' wrapped ui={false} />
          <ImageUploader userAvatar={userAvatar} history={history} />
          <Card.Content>
            <Card.Header>Charly</Card.Header>
            <Card.Meta>
            <span className='date'>Joined in 2015</span>
            </Card.Meta>
            <Card.Description>
            Charly
            </Card.Description>
            </Card.Content>
          <Card.Content extra>
          <a>
           <Icon name='user' />
           22 Friends
          </a>
        </Card.Content>
       </Card>
      </Segment>
      </Grid.Column>

    </Grid>
 </>
 )

 }

function mapStateToProps(state) {
 const { ui, users } = state
 const { isLoggedIn, userAvatar } = users
 const { modalActive } = ui

 return { isLoggedIn, userAvatar, modalActive }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
 bindActionCreators({ modalStateOn, modalStateOff, loadAvatar }, dispatch)

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ProfilePage)
```

My thinking this is because its not getting passed in correctly somewhere.

These are the components which are higher in the chain. The uploaded reverts to the default when changing from mobile to desktop and vice-versa.

```
const LinkNavWithLayout = ({ children, history, data, userAvatar, modalActive, modalStateOn, modalStateOff, isLoggedIn }) => (
 <React.Fragment>
  <DesktopContainer history={history} data={data} userAvatar={userAvatar} modalActive={modalActive} modalStateOn={modalStateOn} modalStateOff={modalStateOff} isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}>
   {children}
  </DesktopContainer>
  <MobileContainer history={history} data={data} userAvatar={userAvatar} modalActive={modalActive} modalStateOn={modalStateOn} modalStateOff={modalStateOff} isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}>
   {children}
  </MobileContainer>
 </React.Fragment>
)
```

And these are the routes:

```
 <>
    <Switch>
     <Route
      path='/'
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
      exact
      render={(props) => <LinkNavWithLayout {...props} data={navBars}><Index /></LinkNavWithLayout>} />

     <PrivateRoute
      path='/profile'
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
      >
      <LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}><Profile user/></LinkNavWithLayout>
     </PrivateRoute>

     <PrivateRoute
      path='/dashboard'
      isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}
     >
      <LinkNavWithLayout data={navBars}><Dashboard /></LinkNavWithLayout>
     </PrivateRoute>

     <Route
      path='/login'
      render={(props) => <Login {...props}/>}
     />

     <Route
      path='/register'
      render={(props) => <Register {...props}/>}
     />

     <Route component={({ location }) => <p>Sorry but the page <h1>{location.pathname.substring(1)} </h1> Page, Could Not be found</p>} />
    </Switch>
    </>
```

So where is should I be adding the `userAvatar` prop to make the avatar render across my app.
Thank you for any input!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `const ProfilePage = ({ history, isMobileFromSSR, userAvatar,...props }) => {` you assigned `userAvatar` to its own variable with the `rest` syntax which means it will not be included in the `props` object.

Your console log appears to show it having a correct value as `userAvatar`.

If you want it to be in the `props` object instead, just remove it from your function declaration like this: `({ history, isMobileFromSSR,...props })`.

Here is a link to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) on rest parameters. Here is the most relevant piece:

> rest parameters are only the ones that haven't been given a separate name (i.e. formally defined in function expression)